# Is it possible to return the ActionLink html from a ViewModel? (MVC3 + Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel

I have a four viewmodels/views which display similar but different data.

Is it possible to have a property on the viewmodel which retuns ActionLinks (or the html for them ?)

e.g.
At the moment on each of my Views I have

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>@Html.ActionLink("My Open Calls", "MyOpenCalls")</td>
<td>@Html.ActionLink("All Open Calls", "AllOpenCalls")</td>
<td>@Html.ActionLink("My Calls Today", "MyCallsToday")</td>
<td>@ViewBag.Title</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

but would it be possible to have:

```
<table>
<tr>
@Model.MenuHtml
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it might be possible to store HTML in view models properties I don't think it would be a good idea. If you want to reuse some code why not simply put this table into a partial and then include the partial:

```
@Html.Partial("_Links")
```

Another possibility is to use a custom HTML helper that will generate those links.